# Building a C program with a GUI for armhf

Tags: c, user-interface

I am trying to make a program for the Steam Link, but I am not sure where to start in terms of the GUI. I have heard of wxWidgets and Qt but I am not sure if that is what I am looking for. Can anyone recommend a program that would work? I am currently making it on Linux but i would be willing to switch to Windows or Mac if necessary.

The Steam Link runs a modified version of Debian i believe and has an armhf architecture

The Steam Link SDK and documentation is on github

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why don't you try gtkmm?

Comment: Off-topic and too broad. You practically need some graphics or [widget toolkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits). If you want to code in C, consider [GTK](http://gtk.org/) or [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/), etc.... If you want to code in C++, consider [Qt](http://qt.io), [libsfml](https://www.sfml-dev.org/), etc... BTW, many such libraries are cross-platform

Comment: It looks like the Steam Link SDK recommends OpenGL ES, Qt, and SDL.

Comment: Thank you Daniel H, I missed that part, I am going to try SDL first